# How to specify column separator for `perl -a`?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read a text file (using perl) where each line has several records, like this:

```
r1c1 & r1c2 & r1c3 \\
r2c1 & r2c2 & r2c3 \\
```

So, `&` is the record separator.

The Perl help says this:

```
$ perl -h 
  -0[octal]       specify record separator (\0, if no argument)
```

Why you would use octal number is beyond me. But `046` is the octal ASCII of the separator `&`, so I tried this:

```
perl -046 -ane 'print join ",", @F; print "\n"' file.txt
```

where the desired output would be

```
r1c1,r1c2,r1c3 \\
r2c1,r2c2,r2c3 \\
```

But it doesn't work. How do you do it right?

Comment: Why a , before the \\?  Are there cases where lines shouldn't end ",\\"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are mixing two separate things.  The record separator that -0 affects is what divides the input up into "lines".  `-a` makes each "line" then be split into `@F`, by default on whitespace.   To change what `-a` splits on, use the `-F` switch, like `-F'&'`.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about the perl command line options look at `perldoc perlrun` in the command line.

Also if you use the -l option `perl -F'&' -lane ...` it will remove the end-of-line (EOL) char of every line before pass it to your script and will add it for each print, so you don't need to put "\n" in your code. The fewer chars in a one liner the better.